# Change timezone docker container

Tags: docker, timezone

My problem is that my docker containers have the system universal hour instead of local hour.
Ive tried solutions that involve changing the dockerfile or the docker run command, but im looking for a solution at a docker service level, so once i change the default timezone for docker containers i dont have to do it manually one by one.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes

Comment: that solves the problem in the way i described i dont want to

Comment: Your question is too broad....can you please add more details

Comment: The solution you provided makes me add certain commands to either the docker run command or either to the dockerfile, ¿Can i solve the problem just once for docker in general, so i dont have to fix the timezone or hour each time i create a container?

Comment: Short answer, you can't